# Can't Change Div background Color on Hover

Tags: css, hover

I am putting text within a DIV.  I would like the background color and border color of the DIV to change on hover and I'd also like the background to change if that DIV is current.

All that's happening at the moment is the text within the DIV background changes on hover.

Here's my CSS:

```
#article_pagination{
float: left;
padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
margin: 0px 3px 0px 0px;
border: 1px solid #999999;
display:block;
}

#article_pagination :hover{
background-color: #99FFFF;
border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#article_pagination :current{
background-color: #99FFFF;
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="article_pagination">
Some text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the space before `:hover` and `:current`. Change:

```
#article_pagination :hover{
background-color: #99FFFF;
border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#article_pagination :current{
background-color: #99FFFF;
}
```

to:

```
#article_pagination:hover{
background-color: #99FFFF;
border: 1px solid #666666;
}

#article_pagination:current{
background-color: #99FFFF;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/R6cHc/

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between selector and hover  `#article_pagination :hover` it should be  `#article_pagination:hover` But there is no `:current` in css. you can use `:active` here.

Please paste you complete code in what sense you want use `:current`

```
#article_pagination:hover{
  background-color: #99FFFF;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6x5FN/)</kbd>

You can't check `:active` in div. If you want to change background color on-click on div then you have to use jquery.

Comment: Thankyou.  This works for hover.  How do I get background to change when active/current?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space from `#article_pagination :hover`

```
#article_pagination:hover{
    background-color: #99FFFF;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

Same in the `#article_pagination:current` too but there is no `:current` AFAIK, instead `:active` and it's for `link`.
[Working Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DWAMB/1/)